# xapply functions, is there a way to know nr of current call, or "context" information in general

Tags: r

Is there any context information available, or a way to make it avaiable, to the FUN invoked by some of the xapply functions?

Simple example: can I know what is the "number" of the current invocation of FUN?

Ie if FUN is being invoked for the nth time, or on the nth elements of a list/vector (assuming it's the same thing, I am a beginner), can FUN read the value n in its code? How?

Thanks for any help/info

---

@wuber's usage of closure in his answer led me to brush up and 
try some concepts I learned in javascript several years ago 
("javascript the good parts" now probably outdated), I made some 
little learning experimentation based on wuber's code, 
In case it can be useful to some other beginner with background
similar to mine here it is:

```
 myFunConstr <- function(startVal) { 
    n <- if (missing(startVal)) 0 else startVal; 
    function(x) { 
        n <<- n+1; 
        cat("Iteration", n, "\n"); 
        0 
    } 
}

sapply(1:2,myFunConstr(99))
Iteration 100 
Iteration 101 
[1] 0 0

sapply(1:2,myFunConstr())
Iteration 1 
Iteration 2 
[1] 0 0
```

Comment: If you need both the index and the element, you can `lapply` over the indices instead of the vector (`x = 11:15; sapply(seq_along(x), function(i) sprintf("x[%d]: %d --> %d", i, x[i], x[i] * 3))`) or use a `mapply` `x = 11:15; mapply(function(i, elt) sprintf("x[%d]: %d --> %d", i, elt, elt * 3), seq_along(x), x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update a variable in the parent's environment, as illustrated in this example.

```
n <- 0
y <- sapply(1:3, function(x) {
  n <<- n+1
  cat("Iteration", n, "\n")
  x^2
})
```

The output is

> Iteration 1
>
> Iteration 2
>
> Iteration 3

Comment: All 3 answers received so far are very interesting both for my  punctual question and my learning of R, so thanks to all.
whuber's directly answers  "can FUN read the value n in its code? How?" has complete and simple code I can cut&paste and uses one of the xapply functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an index to a `list` by creating a `data.frame` with your `list` and a `vector` of numbers.

For example:

```
myList = list("a", "b", "c")

cbind(1:length(myList), myList)
```

Output:

```
       myList
[1,] 1 "a"   
[2,] 2 "b"   
[3,] 3 "c"
```

This will create a `data.frame` with a column for `myList` and a column for an index.

You can then access the index in any function that works on `data.frame` rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Map` or `mapply` iterating over both the object, `x`, and the sequence number, `seq_along(x)` at the same time:

```
x <- 2:4 # test object to iterate over
FUN <- seq_len # test function

FUN2 <- function(x, i) { print(i); FUN(x) }
result <- Map(FUN2, x, seq_along(x))
```